# android layout designing tools

Tags: android

dose any tools existing for our android layout design?
I mean just drag the buttons,edittext,layouts...etc and that tool generate the xml file for our layout..
anybody know about this tool...please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.droiddraw.org/

Comment: can we use this to develop styles,main?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is far better the DroidDraw.. I suggest use Eclipse

Comment: Should this be an answer or a comment?